# On a CW question edited by more users, and with a score of ten, who gets the "Nice Question" badge?

Tags: support, questions, badges

The question [What are some slang words for "police" in countries besides the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/slang-words-for-police) has a score of ten, and it has been edited from three users. Who gets the "Nice Question" badge? Is it given to the OP, or to the user with the most percentage of editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badges for specific posts are always awarded to the OP.